# Unit test can not be achieved in android studio using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

In android studio using kotlin, I created a class with the code below:

```
class Dice(val numSides:Int){
fun roll():Int{
    return (1..numSides).random()
}
```

}

in ExampleUnitTest.kt file I have created the following code to test:

```
class ExampleUnitTest {
@Test
fun generates_number() {
    val dice = Dice(4)
    val rollResult = dice.roll()
    assertTrue("The value of rollResult was not between 1 and 6", rollResult in 1..6)

    }

}
```

The test should be passed only if Dice(6) as the result should be any number between 1 to 6 but as shown above when with Dice(4) or any number, the test passed. that why? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your test checks if the rolled number is between *1* and *6*. With `Dice(4)` the result will be between *1* and *4*, which means it's always going to be between *1* and *6* as well. Or to put it another way, it's impossible for you to get a value from `Dice(4).roll()` that *isn't* somewhere between *1* and *6* - it's never going to be *5* or *6*, but that doesn't contradict anything!

What you probably *want* to test is whether `Dice(4).roll()`'s *possible range of outputs* is from *1* to *6*. But there's no way to absolutely prove that from the outside, not the way the class is written anyway. All you can do is provide a value for `numSides` and then call `roll()` and check the output. That's all the class offers to you in terms of interactivity.

---

A better question is why you want to test this? Your test seems to be written to fail when your code is working - you should be testing that the behaviour *is* what you'd expect, so all your tests pass. So really, what you'd want to test is that `Dice(4).roll()` *only produces values within the expected range*, i.e. between *1* and *4*.

Since it's random the only way to really do this is run the same test lots of times and make sure a bad number never comes up (or you eventually see a number you want), so you can say with a high degree of confidence that it's *probably* correct. Something like

```
@Test
fun generates_number() {
    val dice = Dice(4)
    val allGood = generateSequence { dice.roll() }.take(9999).all { it in 1..4 }
    assertTrue("At least one dice roll was not between 1 and 4", allGood)
}
```

(or you could use a `for` loop with `break` to exit early if one of the values isn't valid, instead of the sequence + `all`)

I just picked `9999` at random but you could use statistics to pick a more suitable number. But the problem here is the random behaviour - because it's not predictable, you can't do a simple *state in -> result out* test with an expected result.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, and I really appreciate your interest. but now I am learning kotlin from google tutorial. and I followed their instructions in the following tutorial link. and they said the test will fail but it did not fail with me. The link is https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-basics-kotlin-write-unit-tests?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-four%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-write-unit-tests#2      You can check it to be certain for what I have said.  see last line

Comment: @Hassan yeah whoever wrote that is wrong - by definition a die that rolls between 1 and 4 gives a result that falls between 1 and 6, right? No possible result falls outside that range, so the test can never fail. There's no trick here or quirk with the language - what I'm saying should make sense, and that's how the language works too. That's the second time I've seen one of these codelabs make an error - although at least this is like a throwaway thing they added at the end without thinking about it (the other codelab is completely broken)

Comment: Now try `Dice(8)` and that *can* fail, because it *can* produce a *7* or an *8*, both of which lie outside the `1..6` range. Makes sense right? But the problem is the value produced by `roll()` *might not* be a *7* or an *8*, since it's random. So your test might pass based on pure chance, and that's not helpful! That's why you need to run it multiple times to have some amount of confidence that it's *probably* ok - it only takes one failure to prove it's not, but one pass doesn't mean it will always pass. Honestly, this randomness makes it a real bad example to teach "your first unit test"!